# Creating a time-series database for a power plant scenario

Tags: database-design

#### Considerations

I need to create timeseries tables in a SQL database, which will hold data about power generated by a power plant. I need four columns there:

```
(
    power_plant_id int FK,
    power_produced int,
    power_produced_when datetime,
    record_created_when datetime
)
```

The reason why I need the last column, is because sometimes we re-measure the power that was produced, and instead of UPDATEing the row, we just add a new one and then we query for most recently created rows, e.g.:

```
power_plant_id    power_produced    power_produced_when    record_created_when    
--------------    --------------    -------------------    -------------------
             1               123       01-01-2019 01:00       25-08-2019 01:11
             1               124       01-01-2019 02:00       25-08-2019 01:11
             1               125       01-01-2019 03:00       25-08-2019 01:11
             1               555       01-01-2019 01:00       30-08-2019 01:11
             1               444       01-01-2019 02:00       30-08-2019 01:11
```

so the query for `01-01-2019 from 01:00 till 03:00` should return:

```
power_plant_id    power_produced    power_produced_when    record_created_when    
             1               123       01-01-2019 01:00       25-08-2019 01:11
             1               555       01-01-2019 01:00       30-08-2019 01:11
             1               444       01-01-2019 02:00       30-08-2019 01:11
```

#### The questions

Now to the questions:

1. What do you think about column names, are they descriptive? Is there
   a better naming option?
2. What do you think about they way I retain and retrieve data? Is "append-new-and-query-the-freshest" good strategy, or should I go for UPDATE? What are pros and cons with one over another?
3. One of my colleagues pointed that if we miss a row in the table, we have no way to find out, because we don't keep information about what's the interval between rows. The solutions for that which I have in mind are:

   1. Set up additional table `intervals` which holds mapping `table_name <-> datetime interval`
   2. Set up scheduled scripts which query the database to retrieve the data from timeseries tables, combine it with table `intervals` and see if there are no 'holes'

   Is this a good way to solve that problem?

If you can think about some good read about this topics, I'll be super happy to accept it :)

Comment: 1) Too opinion-based. I should use `plant_id`, `power` (or MW/MWh), `measured_at` (value is referenced to measurement) and `created_at` (value is referenced to record). `_at` suffix for the timestamp is common practice. 2) None data must be lost. New record is the only option. 3) One simple query will find all records which cannot be found by your colleague.